# Elaborate C++ parsing and the listings package

Tags: listings, vim, sourcecode

I would like to have the colors the gruvbox coloring scheme for (g)vim uses in a lstlisting environment. Is the listings package too dumb to differentiate e.g. between "template", "const" and other keywords so they all get the same color?

Comment: in my experience `listings` can be manipulated to do pretty smart (or dumb) things. You can try with `morekeywords` or with some text replacement for `const` or `template`. Maybe if you put a screenshot of the desired colors and the code we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Listings only has quite a simple pattern matcher designed to distinguish keywords from punctuation etc. The minted package is more powerful (but requires shell-escape to use an external parser). Minted uses the python pygmetize syntax highlighter, for which there appears to be a gruvbox-style customisation here

https://github.com/daveyarwood/gruvbox-pygments

Comment: My documentation currently uses `\begin{lstlisting}[style=...]` and `\listinline|...|` everywhere. Is it easy to go from listings to mint in regards to an existing documentation that already uses listings?

Comment: @apriori try one with minted and if you like it then it's only a global replace in your editor to change them all, or just some, you can load both packages.